# load property file from another project in the same JVM

Tags: java

I have two maven projects `A` and `B` in the same JVM. Project `B` depends on project `A`. In one class of project `A`, I need to load a property file of project `B` e.g. `/B/src/main/resource/foo.properties` in a static block which is something like the following:

```
 Class bar{//this class is in project A
    static{
     //do the magic to load the property file in project B
    }
   }
```

What's the right path to access the mentioned property file in project `B`?

Please help with a working pseudo statements. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: IF, the resource in question is bundled (ie within the a Jar file) OR is withing the classpath of both projects, you should be able to use `bar.class.getResource("/resource/foo.properties")`, which will return a URL to the specified resource. This may require you to build the projects in question

Answer (score 0):

As you already have maven dependancy specified, all the classpath resources are form another project is available into another project.

try this code

```
public void doSomeOperation() throws IOException {
        // Get the inputStream
        InputStream inputStream = Bar.class.getClassLoader()
                .getResourceAsStream("myApp.properties");

        Properties properties = new Properties();

        System.out.println("InputStream is: " + inputStream);

        // load the inputStream using the Properties
        properties.load(inputStream);
        // get the value of the property
        String propValue = properties.getProperty("abc");

        System.out.println("Property value is: " + propValue);
    }
```